# Unit testing for Angular service method with imported third party dependancy

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, angular-services

I have an Angular service which imports a third party dependancy.  I call the dependancy to give me the browser fingerprint which is then stored in the service.

I am not sure how to mock this dependency in the test so I can assert it has been called and mock a return value.

This is the service:

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as Fingerprint2 from 'fingerprintjs2';

@Injectable()
export class ClientInfoService {
    public fingerprint: string | null = null;

    constructor() {
    }

    createFingerprint(): any {
        return new Fingerprint2();
    }

    setFingerprint(): void {
        let fprint = this.createFingerprint();
        setTimeout(() => fprint.get(hash => this.fingerprint = hash), 500);
    }

    getFingerprint(): string | null {
        return this.fingerprint;
    }

}
```

This is the current test code:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ClientInfoService } from './client-info.service';

describe('Client Info Service', () => {
    const hash = 'a6e5b498951af7c3033d0c7580ec5fc6';
    let service: ClientInfoService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [ClientInfoService],
        });
        service = TestBed.get(ClientInfoService);
    });

    test('should be defined', () => {
        expect(service).toBeDefined();
    });


    describe('get the fingerprint', () => {

        test('it should be null', () => {
            let fprint = service.getFingerprint();
            expect(fprint).toBeNull();
        });

        test('it should be the hash value', () => {
            service.fingerprint = hash;
            let fprint = service.getFingerprint();
            expect(fprint).toEqual(hash);
        });

    test('it should get the hash value after setting', () => {
        jest.useFakeTimers();
        service.createFingerprint = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(() => {
            return {
                get: function (cb) {
                    return cb(hash);
                }
            };
        });
        spyOn(service, 'createFingerprint');
        service.setFingerprint();
        jest.runAllTimers();
        expect(service.createFingerprint).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(service.fingerprint).toEqual(hash);
    });

    });

});
```

Comment: In your case, `setFingerPrint` ends up storing the fingerprint, and it can be accessed via `getFingerPrint`. So I might just call `setFingerPrint` in the test, and then verify that `getFingerPrint` returns a correct instance. In general though, it's hard to mock dependencies that are created internally (with `new Fingerprint2()`, in this case) which is why we inject dependencies instead. So you could create another "factory" type of service which is responsible for instantiating fingerprints. Then you could mock the fingerprint returned by that service, and verify its methods are called.

Comment: i updated the test to mock the create method to return my own implementation but it still fails.

Comment: Which test and expectation fails? What's the error? Your actual `ClientInfoService` doesn't seem to have a `createFingerprint` method, but the test does? A live example might help as well.

Comment: I updated the service to include the create fingerprint method.  It is just the final test that fails.  The assertion where we expect the fingerprint to equal hash after calling setFingerprint.

Comment: Is `fprint.get` by chance async? (Does `hash => this.fingerprint = hash` happen right away?) Can you log `service.fingerprint`?

Comment: I looked at the plugin code and it is not async.  We are passing a callback to the get method which is returned with the resulting hash.

Comment: Oh right, you're mocking the fingerprint anyway so it wouldn't matter in the test. Can you create a live example?

Comment: I managed to answer this myself through spies and returned values.  I appreciate your help as it got me thinking on the correct path!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve this with the below spec.  I used spies and returned values to mock the fingerprint creation.

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ClientInfoService } from './client-info.service';

describe('Client Info Service', () => {
    const hash = 'a6e5b498951af7c3033d0c7580ec5fc6';
    let service: ClientInfoService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [ClientInfoService],
        });
        service = TestBed.get(ClientInfoService);
    });

    test('should be defined', () => {
        expect(service).toBeDefined();
    });

    test('it should set the fingerprint', () => {
        jest.useFakeTimers()
        let cb = (h) => {return h;};
        spyOn(service, 'createFingerprint').and.returnValue({
            get: (cb) => {
                return cb(hash);
            },
        });
        service.setFingerprint();
        jest.runAllTimers();
        expect(service.createFingerprint).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(service.fingerprint).toEqual(hash);
    });

    test('it should get the fingerprint', () => {
        let fprint = service.getFingerprint();
        expect(fprint).toEqual(service.fingerprint);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not import 3rd parties directly into service as it hard to unit test them (especially if they doing some tricky stuff like http calls or DOM manipulation, etc...)

It may be good idea to create Angular service that works like factory for 3rd parties:

```
import * as Fingerprint2 from 'fingerprintjs2';

@Injectable()
export class FingerprintFactory {
    create(): any {
        return new Fingerprint2();
    }
}
```

After that you could inject `FingerprintFactory` in your `ClientInfoService` and use its `create` method to create `Fingerprint2` instance.

Also it will be very easy to mock `FingerprintFactory` in your `ClientInfoService`